# Empty maven jar created by bazel

Tags: maven, bazel

I'm having issues using maven dependencies when building with bazel. The problem seems to be that the downloaded jar is empty, with only the manifest in it. I've double and triple checked that the path and version are correct and also used the sha1 to ensure that the correct jar is being targeted.

WORKSPACE:

```
maven_server(
  name = "default",
  url = "http://central.maven.org/maven2/
)

maven_jar(
  name = "org_seleniumhq_selenium_selenium_java",
  artifact = "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.11.0",
  sha1 = "05b50d4072e0e51779b6e9f3594106312061bfde"
)
```

BUILD:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

java_library(
  name = "core",
  srcs = glob(
     ["main/core/**/*.java"]
  ),
  resources = glob(["test/resources/*"]),
  deps = ["@org_seleniumhq_selenium_selenium_java//jar"]
)
```

Calling "bazel build //src:core" immediately fails with "error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist", however I can see that the selenium-java.jar is being created in bazel-e2e-testing/external/org_seleniumhq_selenium_selenium_java, but again, it is empty.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message does not fit to the given code snippets...furthermore I would recommend to use https instead of http to access Maven Central...and are you sure this address is correct?

Comment: The package "org.openqa.selenium" is an import that's from the empty jar, so the failure is directly related to the code snippet. I've also tried your suggestion with https, but with no success. And yes, the address is correct.

Comment: What I'm not sure that bazel does is resolve transitive dependencies of maven jars, but the docs are pretty lacking on this.

Comment: @danut.turta any chance for more of the output log? Also how is bazel-e2e-testing related?

Comment: e2e-testing is the name of the repository in which the WORKSPACE file is located, and bazel-e2e-testing is one of the output locations of the build, where the compiled code and the external dependencies should be created. Anyways, I've figured it out and I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

So, after more investigation on how Bazel works, I've finally figured out the issue and I'll add it here in case anyone stumbles on the same problem in the future.

The main problem is the transitive dependencies, which maven_jar doesn't resolve by default. Instead, there is a useful repository rule provided by bazel called [transitive_maven_jar](https://github.com/bazelbuild/migration-tooling), which can be used to resolve all transitive dependencies. Also, there was an issue with the actual dependency being declared.

In my case, I declared selenium-java as the dependency, however I was only using an import from one of its transitive dependencies (selenium-api). Due to this, selenium-java was not actually being compiled as it wasn't actually used. Once I've declared selenium-api as my dependency, the issue was solved.

Final WORKSPACE:

```
http_archive(
    name = "trans_maven_jar",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/migration-tooling/archive/master.zip",
    type = "zip",
    strip_prefix = "migration-tooling-master",
)

load("@trans_maven_jar//transitive_maven_jar:transitive_maven_jar.bzl", "transitive_maven_jar")
transitive_maven_jar(
    name = "dependencies",
    artifacts = [
        "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.11.0",
    ]
)

load("@dependencies//:generate_workspace.bzl", "generated_maven_jars")
generated_maven_jars()
```

Final BUILD:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

java_library(
    name = "core",
    srcs = glob(
        ["main/core/**/*.java"]
    ),
    resources = glob(["test/resources/*"]),
    deps = [
        "@org_seleniumhq_selenium_selenium_api//jar"
    ]
)
```

Note that I've still not fully understood how bazel works, so part of what I said might not be precisely correct, in which case, please let me know, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: unlike maven, in bazel dependencies need to specify explicitly and there is no default support for transitive dependencies. seems you've got code work for you, see if you can make use of [https://github.com/johnynek/bazel-deps] for dependency.